# Correct way to save a date in a database

Tags: sql

I often need to store a date in my database, my question is what is universally the best way to do this.

I have used several methods in the past, for example:

- Storing dayOfMonth, month and year in separate columns
- Using a timestamp
- Using DATE/DATETIME

Comment: Afaik there is not a "best" way to do this. Your choice should be based on your current needs and maybe the future needs of the business.

Comment: I prefer using a timestamp in unix timestamp Epoch

Comment: `Storing dayOfMonth, month and year in separate columns` Oh my… :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all that depends of course on the datatypes your DBMS supports. Does it have separate `DATE` and `TIME` types, is there a `DATETIME` and maybe a timestamp, possibly with and without a timezone?

If I want to store a date (like `DATE '2022-02-21'`), I'd use `DATE`. If I want to store a date and time (like `TIMESTAMP '2022-02-21 15:16:17'`), I would probably use `DATETIME`. And only if I needed more precision (fractions of a second) or a timezone would I use a `TIMESTAMP`.

By using the appropriate data type, I can use all date functions and date arithmetic available and have it guaranteed that no invalid data makes it into the database (such as February 30).

And then there are other cases. Say, I want to store birth dates including the birth time, but sometimes I don't know the time. Then I'd store date and time separately (in `DATE` and `TIME` columns) and make the date not nullable and the time nullable. Or if I want to store repeating calendar events (every February 3, every Monday and Tuesday, etc.), I will probably decide to have separate columns for year (`INT`), month (`INT`), day (`INT`), weekday (`INT` or `VARCHAR`). And some matching check constraits of course.

Answer (score 3):

I always save datetime in one field in ISO 8601 datetime format, always in UTC timezone `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss`. That way

- you won't face problems with understanding this time for any timezone or transmitting it to another one.
- everyone who has access to DB can do mind calculations to understand the time in his/her timezone, no local format misunderstandings
- you won't update database structure in future if you understand that date only is not enough anymore

I didn't face any business needs or specific queries to work better with any another approach.

Comment: I have to add that the exception to this rule may be any astro-physical applications or apps in sphere where is critical to save the most exact datetime. I mean the clock we use is not physically correct: for now each day on the Earth contains in average 23h5min4.091sec (Sideral day). Another way is for time on another planets or objects that are close to strong gravital fields. Here I'd better rely on specific use cases.

Comment: According to google it's "23 h 56 min 4.0905". Just in case somebody (like me) stumbles over this very short day.